# Why does ArcGIS Desktop 10 say "ArcInfo is not authorized" after saying "your software has been authorized"?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, installation, arcgis-license-manager

Here is my sequence of actions:

- Install ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.0.2414
- Start ArcGIS Administrator application
- Click "Desktop"
- "ArcInfo (Single Use)" option is automatically chosen and I am unable to change it to ArcView or ArcEditor. My code is supposed to be for Basic version though.
- Click "Authorize Now..."
- Select "I have installed my software and need to authorize it"
- Select "Authorize with ESRI now using the Internet"
- Enter address; organization, industry, specialization
- Enter authorization number into ArcInfo Single Use field (ESUXXXXXXXXX).
- Select "I do not want to authorize extensions at this time."
- See "Authorizing software..." progress bar
- See success message:
  "Congratulations, your software has been authorized and is now ready for use."

[image]

Then I try to launch ArcInfo, ArcMap, ArcGlobe, ArcCatalog or ArcScene and all give me the following error: "ArcInfo is not authorized for use."

[image]

Do you know why this happening?
And what would you recommend me to do?

Comment: When you choose the ArcInfo product are you selecting "concurrent use" or "single use"?

Comment: Your graphic doesn't show which product you selected in the Administrator app.  Note that 10.0 has been retired for nearly a year, so it's possible your license applies to a different product

Comment: Whyzar, "ArcInfo (Single Use)" option is auto-selected for me.

Comment: ArcInfo is a license level. Your product code used to authorize was editor or viewer level licennse. The difference between them is just access to functionality within the application

Comment: If you "have a Basic license" (new information) you need to select a Basic software capability (which, way back at 10.0, was called "ArcView")

Comment: I managed to reach Esri customer service (they usually work until 5pm) and they were very helpful.

Comment: First they recommended to delete C:\ProgramData\FLEXnet, but I could not do that as the folder was in use by some application we could not find. Then they told me for Windows 10 I had to install a new version ArcGIS 10.5 rather than old 10.0. Now it all worked.